# Create function in MonetDB

Tags: sql, function, monetdb

I'm trying to add a simple function in to monetDB at database level, which just does sum(n) and returns the result

```
create function sys.foo(number int)
returns int
begin
declare tsum int;
set tsum = 0;
while number > 0 do
set tsum = tsum + number;
set number = number -1;
end while;
return tsum;
end;
```

While attempting to execute the above code i'm seeing error as follows

> [Error Code: 0, SQL State: 42000]  syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting WHILE: end of input stream in "create function sys.foo(number int)

I could add the same function in to MySQL, and it works!!

```
>select sys.foo(10) 
sys.foo(10)
-----------
55
```

Could some one please let me know whats going wrong here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Voting to close.

Comment: were you able add the function successfully? which version of monet you are using? i'm trying with oct2014-SP4 version in windows environment.

Comment: I used a [Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/monetdb/monetdb-r-docker/).  MonetDB v11.19.11 (Oct2014-SP3) on Fedora.

Comment: Works fine for me as well...

Comment: When I tried adding this function from SQLWorkbench i was seeing this issue but when i tried it  from mclient..it worked!!! thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me (Oct2014 release of MonetDB, Mac OS X)

`➜  ~  mclient
Welcome to mclient, the MonetDB/SQL interactive terminal (unreleased)
Database: MonetDB v11.19.16 (unreleased), 'demo'
Type \q to quit, \? for a list of available commands
auto commit mode: on
sql>create function sys.foo(number int)
more>returns int
more>begin
more>declare tsum int;
more>set tsum = 0;
more>while number > 0 do
more>set tsum = tsum + number;
more>set number = number -1;
more>end while;
more>return tsum;
more>end;
operation successful (2.127ms)`

`sql>select sys.foo(10);
+------------------+
| foo_single_value |
+==================+
|               55 |
+------------------+
1 tuple (1.771ms)`

Comment: looks problem is seen when you use SQLWorkbench to this...Worked when i tried it from mclient...Thank you!